# I want to filter the output

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have created the following script

```
echo -n "Input your target"
read target;

echo "[*] Get Whois .."
whois $ target >> whois.txt
```

I want to display the string "Domain" only into the terminal which is inside the whois.txt file

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but variables are used like this: `whois "$target"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send all output to a file but only some output to the screen, use `tee` and `grep`:

```
$ target=google.com
$ whois "$target" | tee -a whois.txt | grep -i domain
   Domain Name: GOOGLE.COM
   Registry Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
   Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
   [...snip...]
```

#### How it works

1. `tee -a whois.txt`

   This sends the output of `whois` to the file `whois.txt` and *also* to stdout.  `-a` tells `tee` to append to the file rather than overwrite it.
2. `grep -i domain`

   This accepts input from `tee`, filters it, and displays the result on the screen.